# extracting attributes from xml using perl

Tags: perl

xml file is like this

```
<properties>
    <property object="tournament_stage" objectFK="820745" type="metadata" name="International" value="no" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-07-28 08:58:34" id="10533355"/>
    <property object="tournament_stage" objectFK="820745" type="metadata" name="Cup" value="no" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-07-28 08:58:34" id="10533356"/>
    <property object="tournament_stage" objectFK="820745" type="metadata" name="Live" value="yes" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-07-28 08:58:35" id="10533357"/>
    <property object="tournament_stage" objectFK="820745" type="metadata" name="Note" value="LIVE:DK: Goalscores (from the list) and Spectators (Redcards, Yellowcards, (Lineup, Formation and Subs. added from Pakistan For all light matches (not livestats matches)) (Squads : DK)" del="no" n="1" ut="2010-08-20 18:34:32" id="10533358"/>
    <property object="tournament_stage" objectFK="820745" type="metadata" name="Ranking" value="1" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-07-28 08:58:35" id="10533359"/>
</properties>
```

here is the xml file for which I want to extract objectFK value and id also I want to count number of objects 
this means if the starting line in the tree is "property object" then count it as 1.
for here there is 3 object.

I want to use cpan module only.

Comment: Use an [XML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/search?q=XML%3A%3AParser)

Answer (score 2):

Just use an XML Parser like [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

for my $property ($xml->findnodes('//property')) {
    print $property->getAttribute('objectFK') . ' ' . $property->getAttribute('id') . "\n";
}

__DATA__
    <properties>
        <property object="tournament_stage" objectFK="820745" type="metadata" name="International" value="no" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-07-28 08:58:34" id="10533355"/>
        <property object="tournament_stage" objectFK="820745" type="metadata" name="Cup" value="no" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-07-28 08:58:34" id="10533356"/>
        <property object="tournament_stage" objectFK="820745" type="metadata" name="Live" value="yes" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-07-28 08:58:35" id="10533357"/>
        <property object="tournament_stage" objectFK="820745" type="metadata" name="Note" value="LIVE:DK: Goalscores (from the list) and Spectators (Redcards, Yellowcards, (Lineup, Formation and Subs. added from Pakistan For all light matches (not livestats matches)) (Squads : DK)" del="no" n="1" ut="2010-08-20 18:34:32" id="10533358"/>
        <property object="tournament_stage" objectFK="820745" type="metadata" name="Ranking" value="1" del="no" n="0" ut="2010-07-28 08:58:35" id="10533359"/>
    </properties>
```

Outputs:

```
820745 10533355
820745 10533356
820745 10533357
820745 10533358
820745 10533359
```